# Data transmission Pi/MCP3008

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

I have a question regarding data transmisison from a Raspberry Pi to a mcp3008. It is just a theoretical one. When they exchange the bytes does the master send 1 byte and receives 1 byte. Then sends the 2nd byte and receives 2nd byte.. OR does the master send 3 bytes and receives 3 bytes after that. From my understanding it is the first one, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adafruit's library for the MCP3008 has your answer. Check out the [`read_adc()`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008/blob/master/Adafruit_MCP3008/MCP3008.py#L49) function:

```py
def read_adc(self, adc_number):
    """Read the current value of the specified ADC channel (0-7).  The values
    can range from 0 to 1023 (10-bits).
    """
    assert 0 <= adc_number <= 7, 'ADC number must be a value of 0-7!'
    # Build a single channel read command.
    # For example channel zero = 0b11000000
    command = 0b11 << 6                  # Start bit, single channel read
    command |= (adc_number & 0x07) << 3  # Channel number (in 3 bits)
    # Note the bottom 3 bits of command are 0, this is to account for the
    # extra clock to do the conversion, and the low null bit returned at
    # the start of the response.
    resp = self._spi.transfer([command, 0x0, 0x0])
    # Parse out the 10 bits of response data and return it.
    result = (resp[0] & 0x01) << 9
    result |= (resp[1] & 0xFF) << 1
    result |= (resp[2] & 0x80) >> 7
    return result & 0x3FF
```

It appears that it sends a three-byte command (where only one byte is non-zero):

```py
resp = self._spi.transfer([command, 0x0, 0x0])
```

The response is three bytes which contains the packed 10-bit ADC value.

```py
resp = self._spi.transfer([command, 0x0, 0x0])
# Parse out the 10 bits of response data and return it.
result = (resp[0] & 0x01) << 9
result |= (resp[1] & 0xFF) << 1
result |= (resp[2] & 0x80) >> 7
```